# Error when attempting to run a discord bot

Tags: python, discord

I have been running into an unusual issue where I have no idea how to solve. I am attempting to start coding a discord bot and have been following a tutorial, however, when I run the following line of code it gives an error. I have changed the token in before posting this.

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
token = os.getenv('NjgzODg1NjczNjg5OTA3MjE1.XlyOfw.UMm8vjHOgEbaSgfRMUglAimOP7Q')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(token)  # The error occurs here
```

Any help with trying to run this would be greatly appreciated.

Error given:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jeffr/PycharmProjects/HypixelAPI/DiscordStatsBot.py", line 18, in <module>
    client.run(token)
  File "C:\Users\Jeffr\PycharmProjects\HypixelAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Jeffr\PycharmProjects\HypixelAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jeffr\PycharmProjects\HypixelAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Jeffr\PycharmProjects\HypixelAPI\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Comment: Please include the error that you're getting

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you didn't change `token` but system's variable which keeps `token` - but it makes no sense. If `'NjgzOD...'` is token then you should assign `token = 'NjgzOD ...'`

Comment: @furas I included the error message

Comment: error shows that `token` has `None` because `os.getenv()` couldn't get value from system's variable `'NjgzOD...`. if `'NjgzOD...` is your token (not system's variable) then you should assign directly `token = 'NjgzOD...'`

Comment: @furas I just changed the token = "Njgz0D..." and it did fix the issue. Thanks a ton, was simply following a tutorial and was unsure in why it was giving me an error.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation you have to assign token directly

```
token = 'NjgzODg1NjczNjg5OTA3MjE1.XlyOfw.UMm8vjHOgEbaSgfRMUglAimOP7Q'
```

Function `os.getenv()` is used to get value from system's variable - ie. from `'DISCORD_TOKEN'`

```
token = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
```

This way you don't keep `token` directly in code and you can safely share code on forums or GitHub.

If code works then you can search information how to set system's variable and then you can use `os.getenv()`.